# Calling SSL_write() when SSL_read() returned WANT_READ

Tags: c, openssl, nonblocking

I'm working on a client-application that uses OpenSSL for TLS using non-blocking I/O. Both sides of the connection may write at any time, indicating some state-change. So I need to check the socket regularly for new data to become available. If nothing has been received my code should immediately continue with the next task: sending new data from the client to the server.

But I'm not sure, how I can do this with the OpenSSL-API: Calling `SSL_read()` on a socket where no data has been received (as the other side did not send anything) always results in an error-code of `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` (or even `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` in case of a renegotiation). In that case may I just continue with the next task and call `SSL_write()` to write other data to server?

The man-page doesn't talk about this in detail. It just mentions that the arguments of the repeated read-call need to be exactly the same as before. The book *Network Security with OpenSSL* by Viega et. al. contains an example of non-blocking I/O. But the author waits for `SSL_read()` to succeed (reading 1 or more bytes) and only then calls `SSL_write()` to send data to the other side, which means that no write-operation is possible until data from the other side has been received. For my purpose this would not work.

In a nutshell: If `SSL_read()` returns with `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` or `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` may I just call `SSL_write()` with other data before I repeat the read? And if not, how can I achieve that read-if-available-and-write-thing?

Answer (score 0):

`SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` or `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` does not necessarily mean an error condition. It signifies that in order to proceed further, Read or write must be done first.

Hence, if your `SSL_read` is returning either one of these. If you have to wait the condition to be fulfilled just the example in the book that you have mentioned. Untill then calling any other SSL API including `SSL_write` will not work.

Perhaps, you can use ,if not used, select/poll/epoll or whatever to know any network activity on your socket

Comment: Thank you dlmeetei for your time! My problem is that even if poll tells that the socket is readable, SSL_read() may return WANT_READ if not a full TLS-record has been received. So I'm still stuck in the read. Furthermore if it only became readable as part of the renegotiation (initiated by the other side) I'm stuck in the read although the other side has send nothing... Or am I wrong about this?